# Conway's Game of Life Loop Logic

Tags: java, arrays, conways-game-of-life

When I run my program my output stays the same after the first run of the while loop. Why is testgrid not being set to the new value of copygrid after each pass?

The loop is directly under the comment //Run again for x generations

```
package assignment2;
/**
 * @author jaw209
 * Date: 2/24/14
 * Purpose: Conway's Game of Life Program
 */
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Assignment2 {

    private static int livecount;
    static char[][] copygrid = new char[30][30];


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        String inputfile;
        String output;
        String generations;
        char[][] testgrid = new char[30][30];
//Fills array copygrid with -        
        for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++){
            for(int x= 0; x < 30; x++){
                copygrid[i][x] = '-';
                }
            }

//Input file = L:\Java 2\Assignment2\Sample input.txt  

//Inputs from file to char array        
        inputfile = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Where is the input file?   Ex: C:\\users\\public\\desktop\\input.txt ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner (new FileReader(inputfile)); 
        char[] chararray = new char[904];
        String allvalues = null;
        do {
            String values = input.next();
            allvalues = allvalues + values;
        }
        while(input.hasNextLine());
        chararray = allvalues.toCharArray();

//Reads values in chararray into multidimensional array       
        char[][] grid1 =  new char[30][30]; 
        int i = 4;
        for(int row = 0; row < 30; row++){
            for(int col = 0; col < 30; col++){
                grid1 [row][col] = chararray[i]; 
                i++;
                    System.out.print(grid1[row][col]);
                        }
                    System.out.println();
                    }

//Finds how many generations should be calculated        
        generations = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("How many generations should be calculated?");
        int gens = Integer.parseInt(generations);

//Prompts for output file
        output = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Where is the output file?");
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(output); 

//Runs the cycle once      
        for (int row = 0; row < 30; row++){
            for (int col = 0; col < 30; col ++){
                if (status(grid1[row][col])){
                    liveSurrounding(grid1, row, col);
                    moves(row, col);
                }
                else if (!status(grid1[row][col])){
                    //run 3 checker
                  if (liveSurrounding(grid1, row, col) == 3){
                  copygrid[row][col] = 'X';
                  }     
                }

            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Generation: 1");
        printCopy();

//Run again for x generations
        int count = 1;
        while (count <= gens){
        //copies old value of copygrid into new array    
            for(int e = 0; e < 30; e++){
                for(int f = 0; f < 30; f++){
                testgrid[e][f] = copygrid[e][f];
                }
            }  

       //Reset copy grid to blank
            for(int v = 0; v < 30; v++){
            for(int x= 0; x < 30; x++){
                copygrid[v][x] = '-';
                }
            }

       //Run through generation methods
            for (int row = 0; row < 30; row++){
            for (int col = 0; col < 30; col ++){
                if (status(testgrid[row][col])){
                    liveSurrounding(testgrid, row, col);
                    moves(row, col);
                }
                else if (!status(testgrid[row][col])){
                    //run 3 checker
                  if (liveSurrounding(testgrid, row, col) == 3){
                  copygrid[row][col] = 'X';
                  }     
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
        int oneoff = count+1;
        System.out.print("Generation: " + oneoff);
        printCopy();
        count++;
        }

    }


//Check to see if cell is live or dead    
    public static boolean status(char value){  
            if (value == 'X'){
                return true;
            } else {
            return false;
            }
        }

//See if neighbor is alive or dead    
    public static int liveSurrounding(char [][] grid, int a, int b){

        livecount = 0;

        if (a > 0 && grid[a-1][b] == 'X'){
            livecount++;
        }
        if (a > 0 && b < grid.length - 1 && grid[a-1][b+1] == 'X'){
            livecount++;
        } 
        if (b < grid.length - 1 && grid[a][b+1] == 'X'){
            livecount++;
        }
        if (a < grid.length - 1 && b < grid.length - 1 && grid[a+1][b+1] == 'X'){
            livecount++;
        }
        if (a < grid.length - 1 && grid[a+1][b] == 'X'){
            livecount++;
        }
        if (a < grid.length - 1 && b > 0 && grid[a+1][b-1] == 'X'){
            livecount++;
        }
        if (b > 0 && grid[a][b-1] == 'X'){
            livecount++;
        }
        if (a > 0 && b > 0 && grid[a-1][b-1] == 'X'){
            livecount++;
        }
        else {
        grid[a][b] = '-';
        }
        return livecount;
    }   

//Adjust alive cells for each condition    
    public static char[][] moves(int a, int b){

        switch(livecount){
            case 0: copygrid[a][b] = 'X'; break;
            case 1: copygrid[a--][b] = 'X'; copygrid[a][b] = '-'; break;
            case 2: copygrid[a][b++] = 'X'; copygrid[a][b] = '-'; break;
            case 3: copygrid[a][b--] = 'X'; copygrid[a][b] = '-'; break;
            case 4: copygrid[a++][b] = 'X'; copygrid[a][b] = '-'; break;
            case 5: copygrid[a--][b++] = 'X'; copygrid[a][b] = '-'; break;
            case 6: copygrid[a++][b--] = 'X'; copygrid[a][b] = '-'; break; 
            case 7: copygrid[a--][b--] = 'X'; copygrid[a][b] = '-';  break;
            case 8: copygrid[a++][b++] = 'X';copygrid[a][b] = '-';  break;
            default:
        }

                    return copygrid;         
    }    

//method to print out formatted copygrid    
    public static void printCopy(){
for (int row = 0; row < 30; row++){
    System.out.println();
    for (int col = 0; col < 30; col++){
            System.out.print(copygrid[row][col]);
            }
        }
System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: This is the point where you need to read up on using a debugger. Then step through your program line by line and see what's happening. Having somebody point out the answer to you here is going to deprive you of this. Seriously, it's easy and it's probably the most important programmer skill for professionals.

Comment: A good place to start would be to learn how to use functions. It will make your life a lot easier, and it will make your code a lot easier to read.

Comment: Using a debugger is a good tip, but you could start by simply printing some variables/debug messages. And you really should be using functions. Reusability is convenient.

Comment: I apologize for the very very sloppy code, but I have spent endless hours on this one assignment. As of now I am just trying to finish before it is due. I have not learned how to use a debugger yet.

Comment: If you make the code cleaner, you'll get it working more quickly.

Comment: That's the cost of ugly code, of just trying to get'er done -- hellacious code that is near impossible to debug. If you were my student, I'd tell you to scrap this and do it again. Shoot if you were to do this, and start and work cleanly, you'll probably save time in the long run.

Comment: I am now considering redoing this. My problem is with reading the input from the text file. The sloppy mess is the only way I found to do it after a dozen hours. I then based the code off how that input worked. Is there a simpler way to read in the values from the text file into a charArray?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely not the whole issue, but I would be highly suspicious of this code:

```
//Adjust alive cells for each condition
public static char[][] moves(int a, int b){

    switch(livecount){
        case 0: copygrid[a][b] = 'X'; break;
        case 1: copygrid[a--][b] = 'X'; copygrid[a][b] = '-'; break;
        case 2: copygrid[a][b++] = 'X'; copygrid[a][b] = '-'; break;
        case 3: copygrid[a][b--] = 'X'; copygrid[a][b] = '-'; break;
        case 4: copygrid[a++][b] = 'X'; copygrid[a][b] = '-'; break;
        case 5: copygrid[a--][b++] = 'X'; copygrid[a][b] = '-'; break;
        case 6: copygrid[a++][b--] = 'X'; copygrid[a][b] = '-'; break;
        case 7: copygrid[a--][b--] = 'X'; copygrid[a][b] = '-';  break;
        case 8: copygrid[a++][b++] = 'X';copygrid[a][b] = '-';  break;
        default:
    }

    return copygrid;
}
```

I'd recommend writing some tests to ensure that it does what you think it does.  I suspect it does not.

As I recall the problem, the next state of a cell depends on its current state and its own count of live neighbors.  This code seems to be affecting the state of different cells depending on the live neighbor count for a specific cell.  It's also setting most of those cells to 'X' and then immediately setting them again to '-'.

There also appears to be some confusion as to whether you're using fields or returning values here and elsewhere in your code.